# I changed site name in sharepoint and I need use previous site url to create a new site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site

I renamed the site name in sharepoint and I need use previous site url to create a new site. Is there a wait time for the old url to be available or any other way to do it? It comes with a 2 after the site name when I try to create new site with the old url.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rename the site, SharePoint leaves a redirect from the old URL to the new URL. You need to remove that redirect.

**Please follow the steps:**

`Note:` You need to have **SharePoint Online Global administrator** permissions.

Step1: List all the redirects

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Connect-SPOService -Url https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com 

$username = "admin@domain.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
 
Get-SPOSite -Template REDIRECTSITE#0
```

[image]

[image]

**Step2:Remove the redirect URL**

`Note`: as long as you enter the old URL (i.e. the redirect URL that you want to free up), the above code will not delete the site—it will only delete the “redirect” site, which is what you want to do.

```
Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/redirect-url
```

[image]

Step3:Create new site

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A redirect site is put in place for an indefinate amount of time at the old URL. You can use `Remove-SPOSite` on the old URL and then `Remove-SPODeletedSite` which will allow you to use the old URL for a new site.